# Code takes forever to come up with a solution

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

What I basically want, is comparing a timevalue (t1 and tuit)(in hours) to determine which method to use to calculate 'S' and 'k' in a function called 'stijghoogteverlaging'.  Then a fitted curve can be made with those values.

I tried multiple things, like putting 'return s' underneath both s-methods.

```
if t1[i] < tuit:
    s = Q / (4 * np.pi * k * D) * exp1(S * r**2 / (4 * k * D * t))
    return s
else:
    s = Q / (4 * np.pi * k * D) * ((exp1(S * r**2 / (4 * k * D * t))) - (exp1(S * r**2 / (4 * k * D * (t - tuit)))))
    return s
```

But then I got a wrong fitted curve as can be seen in the image below.
Now I tried putting only one 'return s', but then it takes forever to calculate and I have to interrupt the kernel.

```
data = read_csv("pompproef_data.csv", sep = ';')
pb1 = data.iloc[1:,1].values-1.87
pb2 = data.iloc[1:,2].values-1.86
t1 = data.iloc[1:,0].values / (60*24)

volume = 10/1000 #m3
duur = [128,136, 150, 137, 143, 141] #seconden
totaal = np.sum(duur)
debiet = (((len(duur) * volume)/totaal)) * (60*60*24) #m3/d
print(debiet)
print(t1)
print(pb1)

tuit = 15/(24*60)
D = 2.0
Q = debiet

def stijghoogteverlaging(t, k, S):
    for i in range(len(t1)):
        if t1[i] < tuit:
            s = Q / (4 * np.pi * k * D) * exp1(S * r**2 / (4 * k * D * t))
        else:
            s = Q / (4 * np.pi * k * D) * ((exp1(S * r**2 / (4 * k * D * t))) - (exp1(S * r**2 / (4 * k * D * (t - tuit)))))
    return s
r = 4.0 #afstand peilbuis1 tot put        

poptpb1, pcovpb1 = curve_fit(stijghoogteverlaging, t1, pb1, p0=[100, 1e-25], maxfev = 10000000)
print('optimale waarde van k voor peilbuis1:', poptpb1[0])
print('optimale waarde van S voor peilbuis1:', poptpb1[1])

tijd = data.iloc[1:,0].values
t = np.linspace(0.00069*(24*60), 0.021*(24*60), 1000)
s1 = stijghoogteverlaging(t, poptpb1[0], poptpb1[1])
plt.plot(tijd, pb1, 'r.', label = 'Gemeten bij 4 meter')
plt.plot(t, s1, 'b', label = 'fitted bij 4 m')
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Used values for t1 and pb1:

[image: Used values for t1 and pb1.]

Plot with a wrong fitted curve(time in minutes).

[image: Plot with a wrong fitted curve(time in minutes).]

Comment: `for i in range(len(t1)):`. That loops over all values of `t1` and assigns a scalar value to `s` each time. Not what you want at all! You need to vectorize your solution properly.

Comment: The returns are very different, one only works on t1[0], while the other runs on all t's.

I would really recommend using numpy vector operations everywhere you can, in this case possibly with np.where

Comment: Many times it is faster to calculate both branches (and combine with np.where), than running a Python loop over an axis.

Comment: @jarondl. It would be fine (but slow) to do that if you did it properly. OP is literally computing the entire vector for each value of the input.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, Well, OP's problem was with a long-running script. In any case there are multiple surprising things here. I am not even sure what exp1 or r even are, why they take so long, and why the attached plot has a non-constant blue line.

Comment: @jarondl [`scipy.special.exp1`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.exp1.html). Not gonna help with speed much here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `stijghoogteverlaging` is performing a nonsense operation over and over:

```
def stijghoogteverlaging(t, k, S):
    for i in range(len(t1)):
        if t1[i] < tuit:
            s = Q / (4 * np.pi * k * D) * exp1(S * r**2 / (4 * k * D * t))
        else:
            s = Q / (4 * np.pi * k * D) * ((exp1(S * r**2 / (4 * k * D * t))) - (exp1(S * r**2 / (4 * k * D * (t - tuit)))))
    return s
```

You are iterating `len(t1)` times, and at each iteration, you are computing the full vectorized value of `s` each and every time. That means that you are computing `len(t)**2` values per call, and using a Python `for` loop as your outer loop to do it. As a minor point, you are accessing the x-data as the global variable `t1` instead of the local value `t`, which gets passed in.

Your function should probably look more like this:

```
def stijghoogteverlaging(t, k, S):
    return np.where(t < tuit,
            Q / (4 * np.pi * k * D) * exp1(S * r**2 / (4 * k * D * t)),
            Q / (4 * np.pi * k * D) * ((exp1(S * r**2 / (4 * k * D * t))) - (exp1(S * r**2 / (4 * k * D * (t - tuit)))))
    )
```

This computes `len(t) * 2` values per call, not `len(t)**2`, and selects a value from the appropriate result for each value of `t`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was probably a big mistake of mine, but I'm still very new to programming. Didn't know about the np.where (which might say a lot about my skills).